# How I can convert 4 Bytes from a bin file to a uint value in C?

Tags: c, parsing

I want to parse 4 Byte how this -> **03 00 00 01** to uint in C.

For this I read a bin file and I get the hex value for every index.

Example:

```
...
 printf("%x ", buffer[0]); // 03
 printf("%x ", buffer[1]); // 00
 printf("%x ", buffer[2]); // 00
 printf("%x ", buffer[3]); // 01
...
```

Now I want to save "01 00 00 03" as uint value and save this in a unsigned int array :/

How I can do this?

Comment: Do you know which endianness the file is using? Other than that just read straight to uint.

Comment: @void_ptr: This is bad advice! Better way is to use bitops.

Comment: There are dozens of questions about serialisation/deserialisation of octet-streams. Just search.

Comment: Better to convert to `uint32_t` than `uint`.

Comment: 1) Open file binary 2) read 4 using `fread()` 3) `uint = a[0] + a[1]*256 + ...`

Comment: `printf("%x "` is contradictory with "convert 4 Bytes from a bin file"

Comment: What integer is "03 00 00 01" supposed to represent?

Comment: `unsigned int x = buffer[0] + buffer[1] * 0x100 + buffer[2] * 0x10000ul + buffer[3] * 0x1000000ul;`  . Reverse order of 0-3 if desired.